# How to make unity transform axis look at specific direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, transform

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
 --gun
  \--bullet
```

In unity3d and I want the bullets specific axis meet with the guns specific axis

like this:

[image]

Note the Bule(`z axis`)

And here is the gun's transform

[image]

And I want to rotate the ball's transform so that the Z axis of the ball  coincides with the guns Y axis

like this:

[image]

So How could I do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) should do the job :

```
bullet.transform.LookAt( bullet.transform.position + gun.transform.up ) ;
```

> **LookAt** :
>
> Rotates the transform so the forward vector points at the given world position.

You can specify an additional vector if you want the up vector of your transform to point to a specific direction.

Comment: Thanks, this works, I am aware of the `LookAt`  method, and tried that before I ask the question, why it doesn't work is I was missing the `bullet.transform.position` part, could you give more details why we should add that to the lookAt vector? thanks

Comment: The `LookAt` method requires a point in world space. So, if you want the forward vector of the bullet to be the same as your gun's up vector, the only point in world space satisfying this condition is `bullet.transform.position + gun.transform.up`. Providing only `gun.transform.up` will give you the point `(0,0,0) + gun.transform.up`.

Comment: The difference between a vector (direction) such as `transform.up` and a point is quite subtile. In general : point + vector = point ; (point - point) = vector ; vector + vector = vector. But point + point does not mean anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I understand now, we should always *lookAt* a point, right? :D

Comment: Yes, indeed. The answer by @MrDos is an alternative way, using Quaternions and direction vectors (instead of points)

Comment: this is gold --> point + vector = point ; (point - point) = vector ; vector + vector = vector

Answer (score 1):

I think using [`LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) might solve your issue.

```
bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(gun.transform.forward, gun.transform.up);
```

What this does is that it creates a rotation based on a forward and up vector. So you might want to set something different than what I have in my example, but hopefully you'll get the idea.